# How to model a tree structure using NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot?

Tags: swift, recursion, uicollectionview

How can you model a tree structure using NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot? I would like to make something that resembles a family tree. SwiftUI makes this relatively simple by using the built in `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have to make our node object to represent heretical tree data.

```
import Foundation

@resultBuilder
struct NodeBuilder {
    static func buildBlock<Value>(_ children: Node<Value>...) -> [Node<Value>] {
        children
    }
}

struct Node<Value>: Identifiable {
    var value: Value
    private(set) var children: [Node]?
    var id = UUID()
    
    mutating func add(child: Node) {
        children?.append(child)
    }
    
    init(_ value: Value) {
        self.value = value
    }

    init(_ value: Value, children: [Node]) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    init(_ value: Value, @NodeBuilder builder: () -> [Node]) {
        self.value = value
        self.children = builder()
    }
    
    var count: Int {
        1 + (children?.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.count } ?? 0)
    }
    
    var recursiveChildren: [Node] {
        return [self] + (children?.flatMap { $0.recursiveChildren } ?? [])
    }
}

extension Node: Equatable where Value: Equatable { }
extension Node: Hashable where Value: Hashable { }
extension Node: Codable where Value: Codable { }
```

Next, and most importantly we configure the `NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot` using recursion. See `applySnapshot` and `addChildren`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, Node<String>>! = nil
    
    let root = Node("Terry") {
        Node("Paul") {
            Node("Sophie")
            Node("Timmy")
            Node("Sandra") {
                Node("Aimee")
                Node("Niki")
            }
            Node("Bob")
        }
        
        Node("Andrew") {
            Node("John")
            Node("Adam")
            Node("Suzzie")
            Node("Ricky"){
                Node("Taylor")
                Node("Megan")
                Node("Arthur") {
                    Node("Fred")
                    Node("George")
                    Node("Giny") {
                        Node("Harry")
                        Node("Harold")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - View
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureCollectionView()
        configureDataSource()
        applySnapshot(animated: false)
    }
    
    private func configureCollectionView() {
        let config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: config)
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Data Source
    func configureDataSource() {
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Node<String>> { (cell, indexPath, node) in
            var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            content.text = node.value
            cell.contentConfiguration = content
            
            cell.accessories = node.children == nil ? [] : [.outlineDisclosure()]
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, Node<String>>(collectionView: collectionView) { (collectionView, indexPath, node) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: node)
        }
    }
    
    func applySnapshot(animated: Bool) {
        guard let children = root.children else { return }
        var sectionSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<Node<String>>()
        sectionSnapshot.append([root])
        sectionSnapshot.append(children, to: root)
        
        
        addChildren(of: root, to: &sectionSnapshot)
        
        sectionSnapshot.expand(sectionSnapshot.items)
        dataSource.apply(sectionSnapshot, to: root.value, animatingDifferences: animated)
    }
    
    func addChildren(of node: Node<String>, to sectionSnapshot: inout NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<Node<String>>) {
        guard let children = node.children else { return }
        
        for subChild in children {
            if let grandChildren = subChild.children {
                sectionSnapshot.append(grandChildren, to: subChild)
                addChildren(of: subChild, to: &sectionSnapshot)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Family Tree Result]

If you would like multiple sections, that's easily done as well by modifying the `applySnapshot` function.

```
 func applySnapshot(animated: Bool) {
        guard let children = root.children else { return }
        
        for child in children {
            if let grandChildren = child.children {
                var sectionSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<Node<String>>()
                sectionSnapshot.append([child])
                sectionSnapshot.append(grandChildren, to: child)
                
                addChildren(of: child, to: &sectionSnapshot)
                
                sectionSnapshot.expand(sectionSnapshot.items)
                dataSource.apply(sectionSnapshot, to: child.value, animatingDifferences: animated)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Multiple sectioned family tree]